# ORA-01795 - why is the maximum number of expressions limited to 1000

Tags: oracle

SO is full of work-arounds, but I'm wondering about the historical reasons behind the 1000 limit for "maximum number of expressions" in IN clause?

Comment: For a good design, the limit 1000 itself is big. Practically, you won't reach the limit. Anyway, I have explained further in my answer.

Comment: I would guess the answer has something to do with grammars and parsing.  And maybe how they were implemented 30 years ago.  It'd be nice to see a theoretical computer science answer to this!

Comment: One could just as reasonably ask, why is the number so high?

Comment: I think Oracle is quite old in DB technology, that these limits were made then once and they never had to think about it again. All expression list have 1000 limit. And a robust design never let the users to ask Oracle for an explanation. And Tom's answer abour parsing always make me think that all this limit purpose back then in 70s or 80s was more of computation issue. The algorithms based on C might have needed some limit and Oracle came uo with 1000

Comment: I disagree that these limits are high and acceptable.  Languages should allow arbitrary expressions or combinations of expressions.  A language shouldn't set random limits, and for the most part Oracle SQL does not set random limits.  There's no limit to [compound expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions003.htm#SQLRF52070), why should there be a limit to [expression lists](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions015.htm#SQLRF52099)?  This question comes up *all the time*; this feature is a bug, even if it's not a big deal.

Comment: If history is any guide, Oracle will increase the limit when enough paying customers demand it. Personally, I just don't see the need. If you can't solve a problem without 1,000s of expressions in an IN list, you need to learn SQL (or perhaps the relational model of data) a bit better. Basically, IN lists are not supposed to be used for large lists of values.

Comment: @JonHeller it's completely reasonable for a DBMS to force good design decisions on its users

Comment: @AndrewBrennan I disagree.  Oracle would be much better if it always followed the [zero one infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).  Design and style decisions should be encouraged through compiler warnings, not language limitations.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because, there is potential of being abused with tons of values. And every value in it will be transformed into equivalent OR condition.

For example `NAME IN ('JOHN', 'CHARLES'..`) would be transformed into `NAME = 'JOHN' OR NAME = 'CHARLES'`

So, it *might* impact the performance..

But note Oracle still supports

`SELECT ID FROM EMP WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM ATTENDEES)`

In this case, the optimizer doesn't convert into multiple OR conditions, but make a `JOIN` instead..

Answer (score 2):

This restriction is not only for IN list, but **on any expression list**. Documentation says :

> A comma-delimited list of expressions can contain no more than 1000 expressions.

Your question is **WHY** the limit is **1000**. Why not 100 or 10000 or a million? I guess it relates to the limit of the number of columns in a table, which is 1000. Perhaps, this relation is true in Oracle internally to make the expression list and the columns to match with the DML statement.

But, for a good design, the limit 1000 itself is big. Practically, you won't reach the limit.

And, a quote from the famous AskTom site on similar topic,

> We'll spend more time parsing queries then actually executing them!

**Update** My own thoughts

I think Oracle is quite old in DB technology, that these limits were made then once and they never had to think about it again. All expression list have 1000 limit. And a robust design never let the users to ask Oracle for an explanation. And Tom's answer abour parsing always make me think that all this limit purpose back then in 70s or 80s was more of computation issue. The algorithms based on C might have needed some limit and Oracle came uo with 1000.

**Update 2 : From application and it's framework point of view**

As a DBA, I have seen so many develpers approaching me with performance issues which are actually issues with `application framework` generating the queries to fetch the data from database. The application provides the functionality to the users to add `filters`, which eventually form the `AND, OR` logic within the `IN` list of the query. Internally Oracle expands it as `query rewrite` in the `optimization` stage as `OR` logic. And the query becomes huge, thus increasing the time to `PARSE` it. Most of the times, it suppresses the `index usage`. So, this is one of the cases where a query is generated with huge IN list, via application framework.

Comment: Still seems arbitrary.  We can add a million expressions, why can't we "in" a million expressions?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Perhaps, because Oracle is quite old in DB technology, that these limits were made then once and they never had to think about it again. All expression list have 1000 limit. And a robust design never let the users to ask Oracle for an explanation. And Tom's answer abour parsing always make me think that all this limit purpose back then in 70s or 80s was more of computation issue. The algorithms based on C might have needed some limit and Oracle came uo with 1000.